# C++ modules with nodejs in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, node-gyp

Some time ago I learned to handle the V8 and compile small modules through node-gyp. Going up files with heroku I see each time that node is compiled with his dependences. I wonder if there is any way to compile c++ to nodejs on heroku. Some mechanism, some command?

It would be interesting for increase performance, especially for functions that handle "native" types instead of V8 objects (as simple strings or numbers, before finally converting to `V8::Number` and `V8::String`), which is architecturally complex and reduce yield.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the mechanism was evident

1. Create in root directory a *binding.gyp* with data of the build.
2. Place C++ scripts in root directory.
3. Modify actual *package.json* and add in structure two commands to execute during [install period](https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html) (on each push):

   "scripts": {   "install": "node-gyp configure; node-gyp build " }
4. git add `file1.cpp`, `file2.cpp`, `binding.gyp`, etc. `Commit` and `push`.
5. [Optional] Add flags to *binding.gyp* to silence warnings.
6. C++ module should start to compile with additional packages.

Comment: Thanks. Just one thing. You don't need to use the root folder, you can place your files in a subfolder, and the script line should look like: '"scripts": { "install": "cd subfolder; node-gyp configure; node-gyp build " }'